# How to change SVG Bootstrap Carousel controls?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, adobe-illustrator

Looking inside sass variables on Bootstrap 4 i find the SVG control icon and i'd like to edit the SVG editing on illustrator.
I can open in Illustrator but i can't return to generate the same code...

```
  $carousel-control-prev-icon-bg: str-      
   replace(url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg     
   xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='#{$carousel-control-color}'   
   viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M640,0L240,400l400,400l45-   
  45L330.5,400L679,39L640,0z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), "#", "%23") !default;
```

Comment: You do know that Twitter Bootstrap 4 is currently in alpha phase right? This means their content is "in progress" and not finalized so thing are subject to change. If you [view their icon section](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/extend/icon-fonts/) it just says "to do" lol. I suggest to wait to ask your questions at least until a good beta build is up.

Answer (score 2):

I find the way to replace svg changing the url with the path of the editing svg in Illustrator..

```
$carousel-control-prev-icon-bg: url("edited.svg");
```